# View charging speed (in watts) on iOS

Tags: iphone, charging

Somtimes I am curious what speed my iPhone in charging at. If I attach my iPhone to the charging brick which comes out of the box, it will charge at 5W. If I attach it to an iPad charger, it will be higher.

Is it possible to see what speed (in watts) that the iOS device is charging with?

I remember that both the discharge and charging rate could be viewed using the [BatteryLife](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.rbt.batterylife/) app from Cydia, so iPhone devices have the ability to monitor this information. However, this required a jailbroken device. How do I view this information without jailbreaking my device? A free method is preferred.